# Creating an SQL Database for Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, network-programming

I'm still a little new to programming in C# and I'm a little puzzled about how to create a SQL database which will be accessible by many different computers over a mapped path connection. Can anyone suggest the best way to do this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would caution you against using a shared file database over a mapped UNC path. There is a very good reason that database servers exist. I would recommend you try [SQL Express 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx) if you are looking to save money and have only a small amount of data and a few users.

Comment: I have them conditions. I've come across problems with other applications I have maintained previously so was aware of these problems. If I used the database, would I just be able to connect to it using the usual database connection strings? Thanks for your help!

Comment: also @Adam92 if you don't want to handle some DBA tasks, SQL Azure is pretty nice.

Comment: Yes. You would just use a standard database connection which under the covers is just a TCP/IP connection to the server hosting the database. No file system or share required.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a database using C# code here is a link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10213/Create-an-SQL-Server-Database-Using-Csharp. Otherwise you can just use the SQL Server management studio to create a new database - here's the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186312%28v=sql.90%29.aspx.